# Align placeholder with input in <input>

Tags: html, css

I changed some left padding in the `::placeholder` pseudo-element and am experiencing some trouble getting the input text aligned with the placeholder.

**The problem:** The distance from the icon needs to be identical on both input text and placeholder text. The input text is flush up against the icon but the placeholder is in the correct position.

A demonstration of the problem and my code is below:

A link to my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4jh52b18/1/

Source code:

CSS:

```
   #search-overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  .search-overlay__wrapper {
    max-width: 752px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 160px;
  }
  .search-overlay__search-bar {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    background: url("https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/28403-200.png") left no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
    &::placeholder {
      padding-left: 25px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 980px) {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto
    }
  }
  .search-overlay__close {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    @media (max-width: 980px;) {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      padding: 24px;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="search-overlay">
   <div class="search-overlay__wrapper">
     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="search-overlay__search-bar" value="">
     <a class="search-overlay__close" href="#"> <img src="images/overlay-close.png" alt=""> </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In the live jsfiddle example, you'll see that the input text doesn't align with the placeholder when they need to be aligned in the same spot. What is the attribute to be able to do this? I tried adding a padding-left directly on the input but that didn't work as expected.

Comment: simply remove padding from placeholder and increase the padding of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SCSS (line 23-25), modify/remove the following:

```
&::placeholder {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

The reason why it didn't work is because `&` in SCSS replaces the current selector. Therefore `&::placeholder` translates into:

```css
#search-overlay .search-overlay__search-bar::placeholder {...}
```

Most likely, you used a weaker selector and it didn't apply.